# Service Worker w offline.html Backup Page

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I can't get the offline.html page to display. I keep getting the `The FetchEvent for "https://my-domain.com" resulted in a network error response: a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode is not "follow"`.

Here's the snippet of my service-worker.js which should return the `offline.html` when the network is unavailable.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
     if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' || (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
        if(event.request.url.includes("my-domain.com")){
            console.log(event.request);
            event.respondWith(
                caches.match(event.request).then(function(resp) {
                    return resp || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
                        let responseClone = response.clone();
                        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
                            cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
                        });
                        return response;
                    });
                }).catch(function() {
                    return caches.match("/offline.html");
                })
            );            
        }
    }
});
```

Below is the console.log of my network request (page refresh when offline)

```
Request {method: "GET", url: "https://my-domain.com", headers: Headers, destination: "unknown", referrer: "", …}
bodyUsed:false
cache:"no-cache"
credentials:"include"
destination:"unknown"
headers:Headers {}
integrity:""
keepalive:false
method:"GET"
mode:"navigate"
redirect:"manual"
referrer:""
referrerPolicy:"no-referrer-when-downgrade"
signal:AbortSignal {aborted: false, onabort: null}
url:"https://my-domain.com"
__proto__:Request
```

Answer (score 6):

I got this working / found the fix. It was related to a redirected response security issue in the browser. From the Chromium Bugs Blog, [Response.redirected and a new security restriction](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669363&desc=3).

> Solution: To avoid this failure, you have 2 options.
>
> 1. You can either change the install event handler to store the response generated from res.body:
>
>    ```
>    self.oninstall = evt => {
>      evt.waitUntil(
>          caches.open('cache_name')
>            .then(cache => {
>                return fetch('/')
>                  .then(response => cache.put('/', new Response(response.body));
>              }));
>    };
>    ```
> 2. Or change both handlers to store the non-redirected response by setting redirect mode to ‘manual’:
>
>    ```
>    self.oninstall = function (evt) {
>      evt.waitUntil(caches.open('cache_name').then(function (cache) {
>        return Promise.all(['/', '/index.html'].map(function (url) {
>          return fetch(new Request(url, { redirect: 'manual' })).then(function (res) {
>            return cache.put(url, res);
>          });
>        }));
>      }));
>    };
>    self.onfetch = function (evt) {
>      var url = new URL(evt.request.url);
>      if (url.pathname != '/' && url.pathname != '/index.html') return;
>      evt.respondWith(caches.match(evt.request, { cacheName: 'cache_name' }));
>    };
>    ```