# Django service worker not able to cache page : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

Tags: python, django, service, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to implement django-progressive-web-app into my project and I am having some issues with being able to cache the page.

In chrome I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed
```

here is the corresponding code

serviceworker.js

```
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/base_layout'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin) {
      if ((requestUrl.pathname === '/')) {
        event.respondWith(caches.match('/base_layout'));
        return;
      }
    }
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
});
```

views.py

```
...

def base_layout(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')

...
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    #pwa
    path('', include('pwa.urls')),
]
```

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/convert-django-website-to-a-progressive-web-app-3536bc4f2862

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I used a solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51162311/12148856) thread and it worked like a charm. Hope it helps someone:)

serviceworker.js

```
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

self.oninstall = function (evt) {
    evt.waitUntil(caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function (cache) {
        return Promise.all(['/', 'main/home.html'].map(function (url) {
            return fetch(new Request(url, { redirect: 'manual' })).then(function (res) {
                return cache.put(url, res);
            });
        }));
    }));
};
self.onfetch = function (evt) {
    var url = new URL(evt.request.url);
    if (url.pathname != '/' && url.pathname != 'main/home.html') return;
    evt.respondWith(caches.match(evt.request, { cacheName: staticCacheName }));
};
```